# What is wrong with this PHP code - Unexpected T_CONSTANT

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error in my log

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

The error is related to this line but I'm not sure what's wrong with it

```
<?php 
if ($num != null) {
    $query_string = 'msisdn=' . $num . '&ref=' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "ref", $single = true) ;
    echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="http://www.site.com/exJoin?signup=y&' .     htmlentities($query_string) . '"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
}
else{
    echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="<?php echo TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111'); ?>"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Proper indentation helps finding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
   if ($num != null) {
     $query_string = 'msisdn=' . $num . '&ref=' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "ref", $single = true);
     echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="http://www.site.com/exJoin?signup=y&'.htmlentities($query_string).'"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
   } else {
     echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="'.TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111').'"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
   }
?>
```

Your problem was that you had a `<?php echo... ?>` in the middle of a string that was already being `echo`ed. This had a `'` in it, which was the type of quote used to encapsulate the string that was already being `echo`ed. You could escape it (like `\'`) but this would have your resulted in `<?php echo... ?>` being `echo`ed into your HTML, which I doubt is what you want, instead your should remove this and put the function call into the middle of your echo.

This should be easy spot if you are using an editor/IDE with syntax highlighting. If your are not, look at [EditPad](http://www.editpadlite.com/), [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (editors) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) (IDE). Or [Google it](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+ide)...

Comment: Hi, I tried changing that as per above but get exactly the same error

Comment: Ah got it. I was missing the semi-colon at the end of the echo as well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
 else{echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="<?php echo     TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111'); ?>"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';}
```

There lays the problem. You see the `'+2711111111'`. it uses " ' ". You'll have to escape that one, because it will end your string there.

Also, you do not need the opening tags for php in their... just remove them as you are already in a php-snippet.

Comment: This will still error with the `<?php echo` in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your adding PHP opening tags when you are already within a PHP tag.  You should change to:

```
<?php
if ($num != null) {
    $query_string = 'msisdn='.$num.'&ref='.get_post_meta($post->ID, "ref", $single = true);
    echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="http://www.site.com/exJoin?signup=y&'.htmlentities($query_string).'"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="' . TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111') . '"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo a string containing `<?php ?>` tags

```
echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="<?php echo TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111'); ?>"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
```

Should propably be

```
echo '<div class="highlight"><a href="'.TeraWurflHelper::getPhoneHref('+2711111111').'"><b>Join Now</b></a></div>';
```